# How to implement a proxy site in PHP?

Tags: php, proxy

Like this one:

https://aniscartujo.com/webproxy/default.aspx?prx=http://google.com

Comment: That's a very large question. You might want to do some research which will allow you to break it down into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 6):

Check out PHProxy: http://lifehacker.com/5447726/install-phproxy-in-your-web-space-to-access-blocked-sites

Download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/

I have actually used this at high school on my site: http://bypass.provanix.com/ and added a login.

Edit:

If you want to try it out, login with username "default" and password "default". I'm still working on the YouTube workaround - it used to work, but the site changed.

Comment: An even better script is CGIProxy, which can be found here: http://www.jmarshall.com/tools/cgiproxy/ It contains rewriting logic for almost everything, including JavaScript and Flash. It's written in Perl though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form><input name=url><input type=submit></form>
```

Once the form is submitted you'll receive in your php a post variable named "url" where the user has typed the url to surf, the simple way to implement in php is:

```
echo file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
```

NB: in order to use file_get_contents properly you should have allow_url_fopen enabled in you php.ini

Comment: plz add <form><input name=url><input type=submit></form> add the start. The most basic working proxy!

Comment: This will only act as a proxy for the html. Javascript, images, css will require direct access from the client. Proxies should be rewriting src attributes in the html source code.

Answer (score 0):

Using squid with a custom url-rewriter (maybe written in PHP) would provide all the required functionality - why start from scratch?